# Yii2 load modal from on click of link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii2

This is my **_form**

```
<div class="row">       
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'otm_grading_system')->dropdownList(ot\TestGradingSystem::getTestGradingSystem(), [
            'prompt' => Yii::t('ot', '--- Select Grading System ---'),
            'onchange' => '$.get( "'.Url::toRoute('dependent/get-grading-system').'", { id : $(this).val() }).done(function(data) {
                $( "#seeHere").html(data);
            });'
        ]) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="seeHere">
    </div>
</div>
```

In form dropDownList on change event get url. show below **DependandController.php**

```
class DependentController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
  public function actionGetGradingSystem($id)
  {
     return Html::a('See Here 123', ['test-grading-system/view', 'id' => $id], ['id' => 'seeHereMdl', 'title' => Yii::t('ot', 'View Result')]);
  }
}
```

And this is modal load js

```
<?php
  $this->registerJs(
   "$(document).on('ready pjax:success', function() {
     $('#seeHereMdl').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();      
       $('#grading-sys-modal').modal('show')
                  .find('.modal-content')
                  .load($(this).attr('href'));  
       });
     });
   ", $this::POS_HEAD);
?>
<?php
  yii\bootstrap\Modal::begin([
    'id'=>'grading-sys-modal',
    'size' => 'modal-lg'
  ]);
   yii\bootstrap\Modal::end();
?>
```

My problem is this can't load view file in modal but it redirect to this view page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an event handling problem (not related to yii), instead of  :

```
$('#seeHereMdl').click(function(e){});
```

You should simply try :

```
$('body').on('click', '#seeHereMdl', function(e) {});
```

Read more : [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)